# Unit testing javascript (NOT node)

Tags: javascript, testing, client-side

I am scratching my head at this one, I must have missed something really obvious.

I have a .Net ASP MVC Web app, developed with VS2015, in which I have written some library javascript code. I would like to have some simple tests for this javascript code that I can run in my dev environment, on my own machine. I have no IIS server locally. (The server side code is fine, I use NUnit and VSs Testrunner).

I have read about Mocha (and used it back end), QUnit etc - but anything whose installation and use instructions start `npm install` and talks about running grunt jobs is not what I am after.

Can someone point me in the right direction / educate me?

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: possibly - I did not know that existed!

Answer (score -1):

If you are up for using pluralsight, it is what got me started. There is a free trial and quite a few videos on testing mvc.

Comment: I have been writng tests of one sort or another for my software for nearly 30 years, I just don't know what to use specfically for client-side javascript.